# Suggestions on how to place a sentence of text inside a box with a border around it

Tags: boxes, framed

I have an "XYZ's Law" quote that I'd like to show somewhere on a page vertically centered in a box with some form of simple border around it.  Basically I'm trying to achieve the LaTeX equivalent of how *Norvig's Law* is shown at http://norvig.com/norvigs-law.html where there's some text centred and placed inside a bordered box on the page.  Can anyone begin to make suggestions on how I'd go about creating something of such an appearance?

[image]

I apologize if my use of the term *box* here overlaps with another use of the term that is specific to LaTeX.  I've seen the term *box* come up a number of times in LaTeX, so I don't know whether it has special meaning within the realms of LaTeX that I've gone and unintentionally overlapped here.

Answer (score 7):

To get you started, and following [Jan's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/suggestions-on-how-to-place-a-sentence-of-text-inside-a-box-with-a-border-around/3558#3558) of using [fancybox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox/), you could define an environment such as

```
\usepackage{fancybox}

\newenvironment{boxedlaw}[1]
  {\begin{Sbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}\centering}
  {\end{minipage}\end{Sbox}\begin{center}\shadowbox{\TheSbox}\end{center}}

...

\begin{boxedlaw}{5cm}
XYZ's Law
\end{boxedlaw}
```

And really have a look at the documentation from this package for further suggestions as well as other styles of boxes.

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers have presented several options to draw framed and colored boxes but [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) was missing. Next there is an example using it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text to show centering
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

{\par\centering
 \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, width=.75\linewidth, 
            colback=blue!50!green!20,
            arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, 
            borderline={1.5pt}{0pt}{black!90},
            borderline={0.25pt}{3pt}{black!70, sharp corners},
            drop fuzzy shadow]
    \centering
{\LARGE Norvig's Law
\par\medskip}
\normalsize\itshape
Any technology that surpasses 50\% penetration\\
will \textbf{never} double again\\
(in any number of months)
\end{tcolorbox}\par}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** recent `tcolorbox` versions introduced `vignette` library which produce the desired 3D effect:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, width=.75\linewidth, 
            colback=blue!50!green!20,
            arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, 
            borderline={0.5pt}{3pt}{black!70, sharp corners},
            underlay vignette
            ]
    \centering
{\LARGE Norvig's Law
\par\medskip}
\normalsize\itshape
Any technology that surpasses 50\% penetration\\
will \textbf{never} double again\\
(in any number of months)
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For start, you may want to look at the [fancybox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox/) package.  For some ideas how to create even fancier boxes, look at [this tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/).

Answer (score 3):

Metafun/ConTeXt is great at this. See for example chapter 4 in the [metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf).

Comment: I think this sort of stuff is overkill for the task in question, but the in-paragraph shading of sentences shown in Chapter 5 are seriously cool. (P.S. wish that manual had PDF bookmarks!)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `adjustbox` for this with the following keys:

- `minipage=<width>` for the paragraph box.
- `margin=<amount>` to add some padding.
- `bgcolor=<color>` to set the background color.
- `frame` to draw a border around it (Note: option values can be used to adjust it).
  There is also `cframe=<color>` (again plus optional values) if you want a colored frame.
- `center` to center it the current `\linewidth`.
- `margin=0pt <vskip>` to add some vertical skip above and below.

Note that the order of the keys is meaningful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text to show centering
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=200pt,margin=10pt,bgcolor=blue!25,frame,center,margin=0pt \medskipamount}
    \centering\sffamily
{\LARGE Norvig's Law
\par\medskip}
\normalsize
Any technology that surpasses 50\% penetration\\
will \textbf{never} double again\\
(in any number of months)
\end{adjustbox}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

For proclamations like such, you can also consider using the `ntheorem` package, which provides a "framed theorem" environment.

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newframedtheorem{XYZLaw}{XYZ's Law}

...

\begin{XYZLaw}
XYZ's law states that blah implies foobar
\end{XYZLaw}
```