# Place quotation (dictum) in a box

Tags: sectioning, boxes, koma-script, quoting

### Background

Looking to change the appearance of quotations at the start of each Chapter (or Part). The book is using KOMA Script v2. (Most searches for the `quote` command come back with results for typesetting quotation marks, rather than aphorisms.)

### Problem

Currently, the quotation resembles:

[image]

Am looking for something similar to:

> Good code is short, simple, and symmetrical -- the challenge is figuring out how to get there.
>   ~Sean Parent

(A double line border, a background colour, but using a serif font with the author name right-justified.)

### Source Code

The quotation is defined as follows:

```
\setchapterpreamble{\dictum[Sean Parent]{Good code...}}
```

I have altered the style of the dictum settings as follows:

```
\renewcommand*{\dictumwidth}{.75\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\dictumauthorformat}[1]{\textsc{#1}\bigskip}
```

### Questions

- What packages allow such fine control over quotations (or `quote`s)? (Neither [fncychap](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fncychap/) nor [quotchap](http://ctan.org/pkg/quotchap/) offer sufficient sophistication.)
- How can the aphorism be placed in a `\colorbox`? (Using `\dictumtext`?)
- What is a good way to add double lines to the box?

### Related

- [Suggestions on how to place a sentence of text inside a box with a border around it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/suggestions-on-how-to-place-a-sentence-of-text-inside-a-box-with-a-border-around)

Comment: the `epigraph` package might be useful, but better check the way Knuth defined quotations at the end of his Chapters in the TeXBook and adapt it to your class. Is there a fine distinction between aphorisms and quotations linguistically speaking?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did not use `epigraph`. I wrote my own version:

```
\usepackage{times}

\definecolor{quotationcolour}{HTML}{F0F0F0}
\definecolor{quotationmarkcolour}{HTML}{1F3F81}

% Double-line for start and end of epigraph.
\newcommand{\epiline}{\hrule \vskip -.2em \hrule}
% Massively humongous opening quotation mark.
\newcommand{\hugequote}{%
  \fontsize{42}{48}\selectfont \color{quotationmarkcolour} \textbf{``}
  \vskip -.5em
}

% Beautify quotations.
\newcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
  \bigskip
  \begin{flushright}
  \colorbox{quotationcolour}{%
    \parbox{.60\textwidth}{%
    \epiline \vskip 1em {\hugequote} \vskip -.5em
    \parindent 2.2em
    #1\begin{flushright}\textsc{#2}\end{flushright}
    \epiline
    }
  }
  \end{flushright}
  \bigskip
}
```

The result:

[image: Epigraph]

Answer (score 5):

One package worth looking at is [epigraph](http://ctan.org/pkg/epigraph), which includes a few options for setting this sort of thing.